# Inserir linha e copiar formula linha anterior

Tags: vba, excel-vba, inserir

Estou montando uma planilha e consegui esse código.
Quando eu dou um duplo clique na linha surge uma `MsgBox` perguntando quantas linhas desejo adicionar, caso eu cancelo, tenho um erro de depuração

```
"Erro de tempo de execução: '13'"
```

Gostaria que surgisse uma `MsgBox` "Inserção de linhas cancelado", como que eu faço?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "1234"
' declara as variáveis linha e i
Dim i, linhas As Integer

' pega a quantidade de linhas que serão implantadas
linhas = InputBox("Quantas linhas você quer INCLUIR ?")

' enquanto o i for menor que as linhas digitadas ele vai implantando
For i = 1 To linhas
    'Updateby Extendoffice 20160725
        Cancel = True
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
        On Error Resume Next
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
Next i
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, Password:="1234"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solucionado o problema com o código abaixo!!!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect "1234"
' declara as variáveis linha e i
  Dim i, linhas As Variant
showInputBox:
    linhas = Application.InputBox("Quantas linhas você quer INCLUIR ?", Title:="Adicionar Linhas")

        
    If linhas = False Then
        MsgBox ("Inclusão de linha(s) cancelada!"), vbOKOnly, "CANCELADO"
        End
    Else
        If linhas = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ("Campo Vazio. É necessário digitar um valor!"), vbOKOnly, "Adicionar Linhas"
        End
            GoTo showInputBox
        End If
    End If
     
        For i = 1 To linhas
        Cancel = True
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Target.Offset(1).EntireRow
        On Error Resume Next
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
        Next i
     
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, Password:="1234"
End Sub
```